# Handles Bars hbs is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.java

i have just set up my layouts folder inside view as

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defualtLayout : 'layout' , layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

module use is

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
```

which give me th following errors

> ```
> app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defualtLayout : 'layout' , layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'}));
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: hbs is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what exported by `hbs` module is not a function actually.

You should read the [description file of the hbs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs) and it has tell you how to use it.

> Using hbs as the default view engine requires just one line of code in
>   your app setup. This will render .hbs files when res.render is called.
>
> ```
> app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
> ```
>
> To use a different extension (i.e. html) for your template files:
>
> ```
> app.set('view engine', 'html');
>
> app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
> ```

and another way is using `express-handlebars` module, it could be used on your way.

> ```
> app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
>
> app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

make sure install this package:
npm install express-handlebars

```js
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials'
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `hbs.engine()` like given below

```js
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

**The below code works fine for me.**

```
app.engine(
    'hbs',
    expressHbs.engine({
      layoutsDir: 'views/layouts/',
      defaultLayout: 'main-layout',
      extname: 'hbs'
}));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its working as i change module to

```
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}))
```

change `hbs` to `hbs.engine`