# app.engine('handlebars', hbs({ defaultLayouts: true })); TypeError: hbs is not a function

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Setting up view engine with handlebars

```
    const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
```

Configure mongoose to connect to mongodb

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/1st-cms-db', { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(response => {
    console.log('Database is connected successfuly')
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Database connection failled')
})
```

**Setup view engine to use handlbars**

```
    app.engine('handlebars', hbs({ defaultLayouts: true }));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

**THE ERROR I GET IS**

```
    app.engine('handlebars', hbs({ defaultLayouts: true }));
                         ^

TypeError: hbs is not a function
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) suggests this should be `app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine({ defaultLayouts: true }));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure install this package: `npm install express-handlebars`

You can refer to [Handles Bars hbs is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769556/handles-bars-hbs-is-not-a-function)

Comment: i have installed it and i got this error

Comment: Try it: app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine({ defaultLayouts: true }));